# How to mod_rewrite redirect php-file-url to new path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect

http://api.domain.com/api.php?debug=true
to 
http://api.domain.com/getData/?debug=true

**What's wrong?**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api\.php/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /getData/$1
```

Also not working

```
RewriteRule ^/api\.php(.*)$ /getData/$1 [PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

That did the job

```
RewriteRule ^api.php$ /getData/
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first tell you what is wrong with your two attempts:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api\.php/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /getData/$1
```

This translates to: If the URI part of the url (after the domain and before the query string) does **not** match api.php, translate ^(.*)$ to /getData/$1. You want however to do it when the uri does match that string, making the condition obsolete.

```
RewriteRule ^/api\.php(.*)$ /getData/$1 [PT]
```

You tried to match the query string here with `(.*)`, but that is not how it works. Besides that, in per-directory context (which is what .htaccess is), the url **never** starts with a slash. `^/` therefore never ever matches.

---

If you don't define a query string in the rewritten part, then the query string of the old url is appended to the new url. The correct rewriterule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^api\.php$ getData [R=301,L]
```

Please note that `\.` means "a literal dot". If I wouldn't escape it, then `apisphp` would redirect too. The `R=301` flag will make it an external permanent redirect. The `L` flag will say that this is the last rule to match for this run through .htaccess. This is to prevent other rules matching on the full url, causing all kind of weird behaviour.

Comment: How do I also redirect the POST Data. It seems to be lost with this solution.

Comment: You cannot redirect a POST-request. Simply point the form to the right url (/getData) instead. Otherwise you need to use an internal rewrite instead (without `R=301`.